# Changing colour of text segments in a powerpoint presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint-Slide with pasted, formatted source code in the form of text shapes. Sadly the contrast of some part of that text is bad on a projector, so I would like to change every colour occurence for a specific font with a different colour. In this specific example I want to replace the orange colour:

[image: Picture of source code with some low contrast highlights]

Iterating over all shapes and accessing the whole text of a shape is not a problem, but I can't find any property that allows me to enumerate over the styled text segments:

```
Sub ChangeSourceColours()
    For Each pptSlide In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If (pptShape.Type = 1) And (pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Consolas") Then
                ' Iterate over styled segments and change them if the previous colour is orangey
                MsgBox pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The [TextRange2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange2) property looked helpful at a first glance, but looking at the variables in the debugger I see nothing that looks like a series of formatted segments. I would expect to find something like `<span>` in HTML to check and possibly change the colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textFrame2.textRange.Font` is valid for the whole text. If you want to access the single characters and their individual formatting, you need to access `textRange.Characters`.

The following routine changes the text color for all characters that have a specific color to a new color:

```
Sub ChangeTextColor(sh As Shape, fromColor As Long, toColor As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    With sh.TextFrame2.TextRange
        For i = 1 To .Characters.Length
            If .Characters(i).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = fromColor Then
                .Characters(i).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = toColor
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

You call it from your code with

```
Dim pptSlide as Slide
For Each pptSlide In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    Dim pptShape As Shape
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
        If (pptShape.Type = 1) And (pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Consolas") Then
            ChangeTextColor pptShape, RGB(255, 192, 0), vbRed
        End If
    Next
Next
```

You will have to adapt the RGB-Code to the orange you are using, or instead of using RGB, you can use `ObjectThemeColor`. To avoid a type mismatch, you need to declare the `pptShape` variable as `Shape` - you should declare all your variables and use `Option Explicit` anyhow.

Note that you can use the `ChangeTextColor`-routine also in Excel (and probably also in Word). Shapes are defined similar in Excel and Powerpoint. Advantage in Excel: You can use the macro recorder to get some insights how a `Shape` can be used in Office VBA.